# Typescript not recognizing computed property key names

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having the same exact issue as what is detailed here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948

Is there a resolution to this?  I was thinking that maybe it is a typescript version error, but I am still having the same problem with version 2.0.

Comment: The latest version is 2.4

Comment: updated to latest but still getting the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternate option, like you can create new `obj` variable like this:

```
handleUpdate (e:React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const key = e.currentTarget.name as keyof Person;
    const value = e.currentTarget.value;

    //New Code
    let obj ={}
    obj[key] = value
    this.setState(obj, ()=>{ alert(JSON.stringify(this.state)) })
  }
```

Its working find check this **[CodeSandbox Snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/YvlzV1W22)**

Comment: thanks! that worked. why does it happen? I'm guessing there must be a fix that does not involve a workaround?